# Animation is too slow

Tags: android, animation

I am working on a game for the Android platform. The layout consist elements which should move without stopping from top to bottom. I decided to use an `Handler` and I set `handler.postDelayed(this, 10)`.
the animation "step" is `5px` (It's actually not `px` but doesn't matter for the discussion).

The thing is, the animation frequently twitching and isn't smooth. With every call of the handler, I make some simple checks and use `setX(), setY()` to change the elements position.

What should I do to make the animation smooth? Should I tweak the numbers mention above? Also, I've understood the method `setWillNotDraw(boolean b)` might be useful - How to use it wisely?

I'd be glad if you could guide me what should I do (Kind of "Do and Don't").

Thank you!

Comment: Do some measurements on how fast your code is. Typically, to avoid stuttering in your animations, you should spend not more than 16ms calculating stuff per frame.

Comment: I can assure you my calculations aren't time consumers. It's just 2-3 simple `if`-s

Comment: try using ValueAnimator instead of Handler

Comment: Niek is correct, you need to implement [interpolation](http://www.mysecretroom.com/www/programming-and-software/android-game-loops) to keep the speed of your game separate from the device's frame rate.

Comment: I used `LinearLayout` which contains couple of views. Is that problematic for the animation rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pskink suggests [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/05/introducing-viewpropertyanimator.html) is much friendlier than animating Views yourself. If you want/need to manage it manually, consider [View.postOnAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postOnAnimation(java.lang.Runnable)) instead of Handler.postDelayed to run your update with new animation frames.

Regardless of how you move objects, be wary of how many views you have on the screen.  Moving one view can force the entire view hierarchy to redo its layout -- this can definitely kill animation speeds.  Try animating a single view in an otherwise empty layout.

[Profiling](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) is very helpful for tracking down performance issues.

Comment: Thank you. btw, how do you repeat the `animate()` method?

Comment: You're welcome.  I think you need to `setListener` then restart the animation for `onAnimationEnd`.  If you're only targeting new versions of Android `Animation.withEndAction` is a little simpler.